# SwiftUI - Error - Value of type has no member

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I get errors called

```
Value of type '[Voucher]' has no member 'currency'.
Value of type '[Voucher]' has no member 'shopName'.
Value of type '[Voucher]' has no member 'value'.
```

Here I get the errors (ContentView):

```
@ObservedObject var voucherData = VoucherData()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            List(voucherData.voucherList) { voucher in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditView(value: self.$voucherData.voucherList.value, currency: self.$voucherData.voucherList.currency, shopName: self.$voucherData.voucherList.shopName)) {
                            VStack() { ...
```

And here in an other file the list is defined:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Voucher : Identifiable {
    var value : String = ""
    var currency : String = ""
    var shopName : String = ""
}

final class VoucherData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var voucherList: [Voucher] = [
        .init(value: "20", currency: "USD", shopName: "FlyBurger")]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to access an array instead of a single object, change the code to

```
var body: some View {
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        List(voucherData.voucherList) { voucher in
            NavigationLink(destination: EditView(value: voucher.value, currency: voucher.currency, shopName: voucher.shopName)) {
                        VStack() { ...
```

That is, since List iterates over the array you give it, `voucherData.voucherList`, and sends each element as an argument to the closure, `voucher`, you should use that parameter inside the closure

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to work, but now I get following error on the line "NavigationView":
*The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions*

Comment: @Distace This could be cause by other code that is not included here, hard to say.

Comment: Whats the difference if I write the code like that? However I still get the same error.
`List {
                        ForEach(voucherData.voucherList) { voucher in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditView(value: voucher.value, currency: voucher.currency, shopName: voucher.shopName)) {
                            VStack() { ...`